# Algorithm for generating n-tuples of an m-set

Tags: functional-programming, tuples, racket, permutation

I am trying to implement an algorithm in Racket (without using loop), generate-tuples, that consumes a list of length  *m* and a natural number *n*, and produces all possible n-tuples of the m-set of the elements in that list. For example:

```
(check-expect
    (generate-tuples '(+ -) 3)
    '((+ + +) (+ + -) (+ - +) (+ - -)
    (- + +) (- + -) (- - +) (- - -)))
```

I am having a hard time coming up with a functional solution. I already implemented an algorithm that generates all possible permutations of a given m-set:

```
  (define (generate-permutations lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) empty]
        [(empty? (rest lst)) (list lst)]
        [else
         (local [(define (split left mid right)
                   (append
                    (map (lambda (x) (cons mid x))
                         (generate-permutations (append left right)))
                    (cond [(empty? right) empty]
                          [else (split (cons mid left)
                                       (first right) (rest right))])))]
           (split empty (first lst) (rest lst)))]))
```

This works, but I don't know if I should attempt to use this in my solution for generate-tuples. I also came up with a helper function that just takes care of the "trivial cases" (for generate-tuples), i.e. for the list  '(+ - /) and natural number 3, it would generate '(+ + +), '(- - -), and '(/ / /):

```
    (define (trivial-cases lst n)
  (cond [(empty? lst) empty]
        [else (cons (build-list n (lambda (x) (first lst)))
                    (trivial-cases (rest lst) n))]))
```

Overall, the fact that the tuples are ordered, and the list length depends on *n* is what is most throwing me off.

Comment: I understand you want to code it yourself, but just for the sake of completeness, [combinations](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._combinations%29%29) already does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
(define (append-all lst lst-of-lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      '()
      (append (map (lambda (l) (cons (car lst) l)) lst-of-lst)
              (append-all (cdr lst) lst-of-lst))))

(define (generate-tuples lst n)
  (cond ((= n 0) '())
        ((= n 1) (map list lst))
        (else (let ((tuples (generate-tuples lst (- n 1))))
                (append-all lst tuples)))))

(generate-tuples '(+ -) 3)

'((+ + +) (+ + -) (+ - +) (+ - -) (- + +) (- + -) (- - +) (- - -))
```

The function `append-all` takes a list and a list of lists, and concatenate each element of the first list, in turn, with all the lists of the second parameter, and return the list of the results.

The terminal cases of the second function are, for n = 0, simply the empty list, for n = 1 a list constituted by the singleton lists containings the elements of the first parameter. When it recurs, first it produces the result with n-1 elements, then concatenated at the beginning of all those lists all the elements of the first parameter, in turn, by calling append-all.